# href target window history navigation

Tags: html, window, target

When using href and target is it possible that you can preserve the history in the target window.

eg using A.html, B.html and C.html below if I click on the links in A, I get B or C opening in the same new tab. But in that tab having opened B and C, I can't navigate between the two, i.e. using forward and back. I think this used to be the default behaviour but doesn't seem to work now in chrome and edge.

I use this to display images from some results table and then would use forward and back to "blink" the images.

Thanks
Mike

A.html

```
<html>
  <a href="B.html" target="show">B</a>
  <a href="C.html" target="show">C</a>
</html>
```

B.html

```
<html>
  <h1>B</h1>
</html>
```

C.html

```
<html>
  <h1>C</h1>
</html>
```